# ViewPager: set a different padding for first and last page

Tags: android, android-viewpager, margin, padding

I already implemented a "page peek" feature for my ViewPager:

```
mPager.setClipToPadding(false);
mPager.setPadding(120, 0, 120, 0);
mPager.setPageMargin(60);
```

Doing this I am able to view a portion of the previous and next page. But first and last page show a bigger white space because there's no other page in this direction to show.

How can I set a different padding for the first and last page?

Comment: I haven't found a direct fix to your problem, but you can override `getPageWidth` in the `FragmentPagerAdapter` and return 0.9f, the view will be 90% of the `ViewPager`'s width, but it only shows the next page (not the previous) except in the last page.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to show both pages when available...

Comment: How did you do it?

Answer (score 19):

I had to solve the same problem and I solved it by setting custom `PageTransformer`. I practically traslate the pages when at first and last position. Let me know if this works for you.

```
mPager.setClipToPadding(false);
mPager.setPadding(120, 0, 120, 0);
mPager.setPageMargin(60);    
mPager.setPageTransformer(false, new ViewPager.PageTransformer() {
        @Override public void transformPage(View page, float position) {
            if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
                page.setTranslationX(-120);
            } else if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == adapter.getCount() - 1) {
                page.setTranslationX(120);
            } else {
                page.setTranslationX(0);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: The last item's right padding is smaller then the first's left. Why? :/